# Adding data to array with JSON field

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having problem with my data property.

```
data: function() {
        return {
            conversations: 
            [

            ]
        }
}
```

When I make a request to server i get response with data. I store these items in `response.data.conversations`. It has property named `response.data.conversations[].messages` which is saved in JSON notation and stores multiple items. I don't know how to **ADD** new items to that field.

That's what I have tried:

```
for(var i=0; i<response.data.conversations.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<this.conversations.length; j++) {
        if(response.data.conversations[i].conversation_id == this.conversations[j].conversation_id) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(this.conversations[j].messages);
            obj.push(JSON.parse(response.data.conversations[i].messages));
            this.conversations[j].messages = JSON.stringify(obj); 
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: How to add new items to the `messages` field? It all depends on what kind of data is *in* the `messages` field.

Comment: There is another JSON.

Comment: JSON is just a string. Do you mean another object? Because if so, we need to see what that object looks like.

Comment: A single message: { "author": "test2", "content": "Test Message 3", "createdAt": { "date": "2016-02-02 00:00:00", "timezone_type": 3, "timezone": "Europe/Paris" } }

Comment: So `messages` is only one message? Then you can't really *add* a new object to that. Instead, you want an array of messages. If you can an array, you can do `.messages.push(newMessage)`

Comment: No, messages contains a lot of items for each conversation.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand the problem. What's stopping you from doing `.messages.push(newMessage)`? If you want to add a new item to an array, use `.push`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I tried that before I posted. It was adding new item but the content was plain.

Comment: @nix9 Do you want to add new element as in `{ "author": "test2", "content": "Test Message 3", "createdAt": { "date": "2016-02-02 00:00:00", "timezone_type": 3, "timezone": "Europe/Paris" } }` to `{ "author": "test2", "content": "Test Message 3", "createdAt": { "date": "2016-02-02 00:00:00", "timezone_type": 3, "timezone": "Europe/Paris" } , "newElementName" : "newElementVal"}` ? If so you can use `.messages.newElementName = "newElementVal"`. This goes only if its an single object. If it is an array use what MikeC suggested above.

Comment: Okay, I don't know what exactly happened. Tried again do .push() and that worked. We all love programming...

Comment: @nix9 You can remove the question from SO then.

Comment: .push() added data to messages. The problem is that when I get conversations and any exists I set the whole conversation: `this.conversations.push(response.data.conversations[i]);`. When conversation with specified ID already exists I do: `this.conversations[j].messages.push(response.data.conversations[i].messages);`. With first method what I get is: `{ "author": "test2", "content": "Testowa wiadomość 1", "createdAt": { "date": "2016-02-02 00:00:00", "timezone_type": 3, "timezone": "Europe/Paris" } }`, but when conversation exists I get: `[ content like above but different data ]`